# How to get started with running vue js examples/demos

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js

Maybe a very dumb question, but how do I get started to try the demo here and edit it to test my local server side rest endpoints?

I have for e.g. cloned this https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead, what commands do I run in the demo dir?

Comment: Probably first install dependencies with `npm install` ?

Comment: That particular repo seems to be using [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) for module bundling

Comment: You can go through this to understand setup steps: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the root dir

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

and then opening demo/index.html, but still dont know how to livereload after changes

--update--
thanks to @unholysheep

```
 webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --port 19999 --content-base=demo
```

Comment: You may be looking for [webpack dev server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this document firstly.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html